# Is it a native way to say "I misremembered the time for the appointment"?

Tags: expressions, american-english

Is it a native way to say "I misremembered the time for the appointment"?

Is therer any alternative way to express this meaning?

Thank you!

Comment: Not "forgot," which implies not thinking of it at all.  "Misremembered" would be understood, but is not a common way to say this.  "I got the time for the appointment wrong" would work.

Comment: Politicians "misremember" a lot of things!

Comment: They also seem to misspeak themselves a lot, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *misremember* strikes me as a word that is falling out of common use, and [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=misremember&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmisremember%3B%2Cc0) supports that.

Some examples of more common ways to say, for example, that the appointment was supposed to be at 10:00 but the speaker thought it was 11:00 might be:

> - I got the time for the appointment wrong.
> - I had the wrong time for the appointment.
> - I screwed up on the time for the appointment

Among a handful of others.

Note that it would not be right to use the word *forgot,* as that would suggest the speaker did not even remember there was an appointment, let alone the time for it.

Comment: Maybe it's my age, but I would never use "screwed up" with anybody other than a close friend.  If this is a business appointment it would not be a good idea.

Comment: Thank you very much helping. It is a very good idea to check the frequencies of the phrase by Ngram Viewer. It is a good tool! Thank you!